# mongodb using less performant index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using `mongodb 2.6`, and I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('Jobs').find(
{ $and: [ { RunID: { $regex: ".*_0" } }, 
          { $or: [  { JobType: "TypeX" }, 
                    { JobType: "TypeY" }, 
                    { JobType: "TypeZ" }, 
                    { $and: [ { Info: { $regex: "Weekly.*" } }, { JobType: "YetAnotherType" } ] } ] } ] })
```

I have three different indexes: `RunID`, `RunID + JobType`, `RunID + JobType + Info`. Mongo is always using the index containing RunID only, although the other indexes seem more likely to produce faster results, it is even sometimes using an index consisting of `RunID + StartTime` while StartTime is not even in the list of used fields, any idea why is it choosing that index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note1:

You can drop your first 2 indexes, `RunID` and `RunID + JobType`. It is enough to use just the *expanded* compound index `RunID + JobType + Info`; this can be also used to query on `RunID` or `RunID + JobType` fields, [info here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/):

> In addition to supporting queries that match on all the index fields,
>   compound indexes can support queries that match on the prefix of the
>   index fields.

When you drop those indexes, mongo will choose the only remained index.

Note2:

You can always use [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/), to tell mongo to use a specific index:

```
db.getCollection('Jobs').find().hint({RunID:1, JobType:1, Info:1})
```

Comment: Note that index usage is different between 2.6 and 3.2 in relation to $ors

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Sergiu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39328099/612920) and [Sammaye's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327765/mongodb-using-less-performant-index#comment65990103_39328099), I think I found what I am looking for:

1. I got rid of `RunID` index, since `RunID` is a prefix in many other indexes, `mongodb` will use it if it needs only `RunID`.
2. Concerning `$or`, we have the following in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes):

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either
>   performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by
>   indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use
>   indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or
>   expression must be supported by indexes. Otherwise, MongoDB will
>   perform a collection scan.

As I mentioned earlier, `RunID` is already indexed, so we need a new index for the other fields in the query: `JobType` and `Info`, since `JobType` needs to be the index's prefix so that it can be used in queries not containing `Info` field, so the second index I created is

```
{ "JobType": 1.0, "Info": 1.0}
```

As a result, mongodb will use a complex plan in which different indexes will be used.